# php Exception By getting a class that might exists

Tags: php, class, exception

i try to make a function that load classes that are in the array. but it can be the case that the class don't exists, in that case i want to get an error string that an be places on that place and if it exists than the class has to be on that place.
so i thought i going to use try,catch to catch the error, but i stell get tge error.

```
try {
        $content = $extension::content();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $content = '[undefined extension:'.$extension.']';
    }
```

who can help me out

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( class_exists($extension) && property_exists($extension, 'content') ) {
    $content = $extension::content();
}else{
    $content = '[undefined extension:'.$extension.']';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `class_exists()` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)

e.g

```
<?php
 if( class_exists( $extension ) )
 {
    $content = $extension::content();
 }else{

 $content = '[undefined extension:'.$extension.']';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP5 you can autoload classes. As soon as you try to load a class that PHP does not know about it will run your custom function which will then be able to locate the class or throw an Exception of its non-existence.

Read about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Throwing an exception if your particular autoload function cannot load the class is a bad thing. Unless you pay attention to the order in which multiple autoload functions are executed (and make sure your function is called last), the general case would be that each function has to check if it can load the class, and if not, pass this task to the next function. Simply calling `class_exists()` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, by default errors aren't exception and can't be catched. However, you can use set_exception_handler to throw an exception when a error occurs. Sadly, fatal error cannot be handled with this method.

To check if a class exists, you can call class_exists.